# plastic storage for bottles

Tags: equipment, bottles

I just found out that roaches harbor in cardboard boxes. Not to mention that cardboard breaks down easily when filled with damp, freshly sanitized bottles. Does anyone have suggestions for plastic versions that I can store finished bottles of beer in? [This question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/cardboard-alternatives-to-bottle-cases-for-storage) was posted some time ago but the answer that was chosen leads to a website that no longer exists! What are the current solutions? I'd also like to not have to build my own crate.

Answer (score 2):

Go to a plastic store, a catering store, or something similar and say you are looking for glass racks. There are many versions and something should work for you. Remember to take a bottle with to measure (width and height). Remember to ask about the weight that the rack can handle (if you want to store full bottles in the rack).

OR: Make friends with your local macro and ask if you can have some of their old crates.

OR: Make Your Own! http://www.instructables.com/id/Plywood-beer-crate/

Comment: do you have any urls for something like these? I live in a small town and it's unlikely that we have anything like this in our area.

Comment: I have URLs for South African sites, not sure if that will help you (not sure of your location). Google for "Catering Suppliers", "Plastic Manufacturers". Or go to a hotel and ask where they buy their equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FastRack](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/fastrack-beer-bottle-drying-storage-system.html).

If you don't want to pay that much, you can use plastic containers with newspaper packed around the bottle to keep them from knocking into each other.

Comment: I've seen FastRack but are those also good for storing full bottles of homebrew?

Comment: No, FastRack doesn't work with capped bottles. I suggested it because you mentioned freshly sanitized bottles.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant freshly sanitized as in the full bottles of beer that are still a little damp from being sanitized.

Comment: Also, all bottles need to be the same size.  You won't be able to stack 1L, 500ml and other sizes easily together.