# Aging beer/cider/mead in beer bottles for competition

Tags: aging, packaging, competition

So, I'm in a process of planning for the next year competitions. In fact, I'm little bit behind since I'm planning to do big brews (few meads and beers).

I already had a similar thread about packaging entries using different types of corks, even though I've got my answer I've got more questions.

So, most of the competitions require 12oz bottles with crown cap. There are few exceptions, like Mazer Cup (mead competition). For them you should enter the product in appropriate package (like sparkling mead or 2-3 year old mead should be packaged in appropriate to style bottles).

So, my question is... How should I prevent my homebrew (beer/mead/cider) from oxidation over time in regular 12oz bottles with crown cork if waxing is not authorized? Is there some sort of shrink-sleeve that I could get specifically for beer bottles (and remove it before sending to competitions)?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why would you ever wax a crown capped bottle? Or are you talking about removing the crown-cap just before a competition and adding some other stopper?

Comment: If I remember correctly, crown caps prevent oxidation better than most other closures (except for screw caps on wine bottles).

Comment: 2Tinypriest: I was under impression that no matter how good the crown corks, they eventually leak the oxygen over time. Not sure what the time span is for that. After all most of the aged commercial beers (1-3 years old) are coming sealed with wax.

Comment: 2valverij: Interesting. I'll look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For long term storage with crown corks (aka: caps), you want to keep the bottle upright, this prevents the content from damaging the seal on the cap.

If you are doing long term storage with corks, you want the bottle to be left on its side, or a slight angle, ensuring that the cork is kept moistened by the contents, this prevents the cork drying out and hence prevents oxidation.

Waxing doesn't add much except for style points providing that the cap is on correctly.

See this answer for a more indepth look at long term storage: [How to store beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/814/how-to-store-beer)