# Planning brewing towards an occasion over an extended period of time with regards to storage

Tags: beer, brewing, storage, aging, beer-styles

When brewing for an occasion in the summer, like a wedding, an anniversary party, I might want to make several different kinds of beer. Neither me nor the average Joe necessarily have the time or equipment to brew intensively just before the event, so I have to start during winter and spread the brewing out over the entire half year to make it work.

There is already an [answer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/815/13277) on beer storage on this site with the general recommendation of high alcohol content, amongst other things. I am curious, however, if it is possible to make this more specific, with an overview of which established beer styles might work for semi-long term storage while still keeping their character, and perhaps more importantly, which styles absolutely doesn't work?

The obvious answer is perhaps to brew dark, malty ales, but in my opinion these are not well suited for sunny summers.

Answer (score 3):

Most all lagers if you can lager for months you can have some great beer.

Fruit Cream Ales are nice for summer, can be done as ales or lagers, often mixed fermentation with both ale and Lager yeasts.

Steer away from hoppy beers as this flavor and aroma is first to fade with age. Brew these in the final weeks of your events.

Malty beers meld great with age.

High abv beers do well to mellow fusel alcohols.

Concider Apple Wines (high abv ciders) easy to make and do very well with a little age.

Check out the bjcp.org 2015 style guidlines to see what fits for you.